# Como enviar uma div via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Boa noite! Eu tenho o seguinte problema: quando o usuario clica em "Adicionar carrinho" deve aparecer o item em pagamentos (como mostra a imagem 1).
Como eu faria pra enviar toda essa div por javascript? Ou qual a melhor solução nesse caso, visto que cada produto no carrinho terá um titulo, um preço, uma imagem?

HTML da div completa:

Gostaria de "instanciar" esse codigo toda vez que o usuario adicionar um produto novo.

```
<!-- GRID de cada produto -->
                        <div class="container-fluid" id="modeloProdutos">
                            <div class="row">
                                <!-- descrição produtos + imagem -->
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-6">
                                    <img src="img/arroz.jpg">
                                    <p id="descricaoProduto">...<p> 
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                                        <!-- informar quantidade de produtos -->
                                        <div class="container-fluid divAddProdutosPagamentos">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <!-- Botão de subtrair -->
                                                <!-- nao consigo redimensionar o botao -->
                                                <div class="input-group-prepend col-lg-3" id="buttonMinus">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- Campo p/ informar a qtd-->
                                                <!-- aqui vai setado a quantidade de itens informado no index -->
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-group-prepend col-lg-3 inputQtd" 
                                                value="1">

                                                <!-- Botão de adicionar -->
                                                <div class="input-group-prepend col-lg-3 buttonAdd">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div> <!-- FIM DA DIV ADD PRODUTO -->
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Template:
(.modeloProdutos é minha classe que contem todo o estilo css,
 #bodyPrincipal é meu ID do body com o estilo css)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#botao').click (function(){
        var _template = $('.modeloProdutos').html();
        $("#bodyPrincipal").append(_template);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro: visto que você vai querer adicionar o html acima todas as vezes que o usuário adicionar um produto ao carrinho, você deverá criar uma lógica para add um incremento, **que será um id** -- diferente, a este atributo: **id="modeloProdutos"** (id="modeloProdutos[n]"), pois, em html5, não é permitido um id de um elemento igual a de outro dentro da mesma página.

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="modeloProdutos[n]">
                            <div class="row">
                                <!-- descrição produtos + imagem -->
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-6">
                                    <img src="img/arroz.jpg">
                                    <p id="descricaoProduto[n]">...<p> 
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                                        <!-- informar quantidade de produtos -->
                                        <div class="container-fluid divAddProdutosPagamentos">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <!-- Botão de subtrair -->
                                                <!-- nao consigo redimensionar o botao -->
                                                <div class="input-group-prepend col-lg-3" id="buttonMinus">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- Campo p/ informar a qtd-->
                                                <!-- aqui vai setado a quantidade de itens informado no index -->
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-group-prepend col-lg-3 inputQtd" 
                                                value="1">

                                                <!-- Botão de adicionar -->
                                                <div class="input-group-prepend col-lg-3 buttonAdd">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div> <!-- FIM DA DIV ADD PRODUTO -->
```

**Usando JQuery:**

```js
<script>

$('button').click(function(ev){

 //Não obrigatório:
 let idButton = $(this).attr('id');

 let _template = $('#modeloProdutos'+idButton).html();

 //Geralmente, uma lista:
 $("elementoQueVocêQuerAdicionarOHtmlAcima").append(_template);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Ola Taffarel, muito obrigado pela sua solução. Estou tentando entender por partes o codigo que me instruiu. Quando eu executo o codigo acima, é gerado uma nova div com sucesso, mas sem as formatações do css. Ja tentei substituir o "id" por "class" mas nao funcionou tambem. Sabe me dizer se é solucionavel ? Inseri o codigo no topico .

Comment: Certo. Manda o código que você está implementando para nós darmos uma olhada.